# Cannot access protected property -laravel 4

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, oauth, laravel-4

I am using oauth to connect facebook with my app

```
token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );
```

will give following

```
OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token Object
(
    [accessToken:protected] => CAAIYQeqXeLYBAIlu6fiQKudu0XQxdCya33PC0cEAZCFDQNkV1KCCZBuOEmXyhkv5VU45kU0pDwSCYoVzLBc7AbHti81mVq9xBgMygA2oLfVArqxboRO1QzgSSCcqqgwZA3nszCmVx6M5MHVXYZBB6g1KpWukRbHWyhVxWUzNWzs81MS3ERiMNK6ZAsYRS9zhYNZABZCTh8SK89tYNGOBuwC
    [refreshToken:protected] => 
    [endOfLife:protected] => 1411197432
    [extraParams:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

whenever i try to access `accessToken` like below

```
print_r($token->accessToken);
```

It gives the following error

**Cannot access protected property OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token::$accessToken**

it seems simpler but i am not able to access  `accessToken`.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter should exist. Try : `$token->getAccessToken());`