# How to access values of object - PHP

Tags: php, object

In Laravel, my controller is pulling an object from a session:

```
$token = $request->session()->get('token','default');

dd($token);
```

The output gives me:

```
StdOAuth2Token {#138 ▼
  #accessToken: "oauth2AccessToken"
  #refreshToken: null
  #endOfLife: 1454189319
  #extraParams: array:2 [▶]
}
```

How do I access just the `oauth2AccessToken` value?

Answer (score 1):

Like you would do to access any other object property in PHP, Laravel is just a framework based on PHP:

```
    $token = $request->session()->get('token','default');
    $token->accessToken
```

Comment: this gives me an error `Cannot access protected property OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token::$accessToken`

Comment: which means that Laravel has set this value protected for some reason

Comment: Thanks. that's led me to the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885438/cannot-access-protected-property-laravel-4 "A getter should exist. Try : `$token->getAccessToken()`"

Comment: glad it lead you to something at least )